# Newsstand Kit downloading not working on cellular network

Tags: ios, objective-c, newsstand-kit

I have many Newsstand apps on AppStore. They are all from same source code, 1 source and multi-targets.
It was fine until now. Recently I updated the apps and some of them have a problem.
When trying to download the issues by tapping the download button, it’s not working on cellular network.

Newsstand downloads is based on a tutorial [here](http://www.viggiosoft.com/blog/blog/2011/10/17/ios-newsstand-tutorial/).
And here is a part of my code:

```
NKLibrary *nkLib = [NKLibrary sharedLibrary];
NKIssue *nkIssue = [nkLib issueWithName:bookID];

if( !nkIssue ) {
    nkIssue = [nkLib addIssueWithName:bookID date:date];
}

if( nkIssue.status == NKIssueContentStatusNone ) {
    NKAssetDownload *assetDownload = [nkIssue addAssetWithRequest:request];
    assetDownload.userInfo = @{@"bookID": bookID};

    NSURLConnection *connection = [assetDownload downloadWithDelegate:self];
    ...
}
...
```

After calling downloadWithDelegate: method, there is no response from Newsstand Kit on cellular network.

- If I change the connection to Wifi, it starts downloading.
- if turning off Wifi, then the downloading stops.
- if turning on Wifi again, downloading resumes.
- if turning off Wifi again, then the downloading stops again.

One More thing I can’t understand is that one of those apps are fixed, just by re-building and updating the binary to AppStore.

Any help would be appreciated! :D